# How to create csv file from json

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I have a json like

```html
{
    "connectEnd": 1366.2749999930384,
    "connectStart": 175.91999999422114,
    "decodedBodySize": 3360,
    "domComplete": 10424.984999990556,
    "domContentLoadedEventEnd": 6581.454999992275,
    "domContentLoadedEventStart": 6581.454999992275,
    "domInteractive": 6581.420000002254,
    "domainLookupEnd": 175.91999999422114,
    "domainLookupStart": 12.000000002444722,
    "duration": 10425.015000000712,
    "encodedBodySize": 1279,
    "entryType": "navigation",
    "fetchStart": 0.22499999613501132,
    "initiatorType": "navigation",
    "loadEventEnd": 10425.015000000712,
    "loadEventStart": 10424.994999993942,
    "name": "https://something/login",
    "nextHopProtocol": "http/1.1",
    "redirectCount": 0,
    "redirectEnd": 0,
    "redirectStart": 0,
    "requestStart": 1366.394999990007,
    "responseEnd": 2062.7999999996973,
    "responseStart": 2059.7599999891827,
    "secureConnectionStart": 414.94000000238884,
    "serverTiming": [],
    "startTime": 0,
    "transferSize": 2679,
    "type": "navigate",
    "unloadEventEnd": 0,
    "unloadEventStart": 0,
    "workerStart": 0,
    "workerTiming": []
}
```

I used papaparse to convert JSON into csv and I am getting this:

"Request time","Time to first byte","Response time","Request Response time","Cache seek plus response time","Dom interactive","Dom complete","Transfer Size","duration","Domain lookup time taken","Connection time taken"
693.3649999991758,3.040000010514632,3.040000010514632,696.4050000096904,2062.5750000035623,6581.420000002254,10424.984999990556,2679,10425.015000000712,163.91999999177642,1190.3549999988172

I am planning to use Jenkins plugin called [BenchMark Evaluator](https://plugins.jenkins.io/benchmark-evaluator/)

This plugin accepts csv only in this format:
[csv table image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rTRl.png)

My problem statement: How I change the structure of parsed csv into the desired csv format. Is there a npm package that can give me directly what I want or the parsed csv needs to be converted.

Comment: Just google `node.js csv`..

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way to convert json to csv is to use the map function without any framework:

```
var json = json3.items
var fields = Object.keys(json[0])
var replacer = function(key, value) { return value === null ? '' : value } 
var csv = json.map(function(row){
  return fields.map(function(fieldName){
    return JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)
  }).join(',')
})
csv.unshift(fields.join(',')) // add header column
 csv = csv.join('\r\n');
console.log(csv)
```

Output:

```
title,description,link,timestamp,image,embed,language,user,user_image,user_link,user_id,geo,source,favicon,type,domain,id
"Apple iPhone 4S Sale Cancelled in Beijing Amid Chaos (Design You Trust)","Advertise here with BSA Apple cancelled its scheduled sale of iPhone 4S in one of its stores in China’s capital Beijing on January 13. Crowds outside the store in the Sanlitun district were waiting on queues overnight. There were incidents of scuffle between shoppers and the store’s security staff when shoppers, hundreds of them, were told that the sales [...]Source : Design You TrustExplore : iPhone, iPhone 4, Phone","http://wik.io/info/US/309201303","1326439500","","","","","","","","","wikio","http://wikio.com/favicon.ico","blogs","wik.io","2388575404943858468"
"Apple to halt sales of iPhone 4S in China (Fame Dubai Blog)","SHANGHAI – Apple Inc said on Friday it will stop selling its latest iPhone in its retail stores in Beijing and Shanghai to ensure the safety of its customers and employees. Go to SourceSource : Fame Dubai BlogExplore : iPhone, iPhone 4, Phone","http://wik.io/info/US/309198933","1326439320","","","","","","","","","wikio","http://wikio.com/favicon.ico","blogs","wik.io","16209851193593872066"
```

Use this less dense syntax and also JSON.stringify to add quotes to strings while keeping numbers unquoted:

```
const items = json3.items
const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value // specify how you want to handle null values here
const header = Object.keys(items[0])
const csv = [
  header.join(','), // header row first
  ...items.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','))
].join('\r\n')

console.log(csv)
```

Comment: this is not the output I require. I need the structure to be in this format:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rTRl.png